# Magento: how to get the attributes that belong to an attribute set?

Tags: magento

Having an attribute set, how can I get a list of the attributes it contains (or better yet, just the custom attributes that don't belong to the Default attribute set)?

The attribute set itself can be obtained in several ways, such as:

```
$entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType('catalog_product')->getTypeId();
$attributeSet = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')->setEntityTypeFilter($entityTypeId)->addFilter('attribute_set_name', 'Default');
```

Note that I need to use the attribute set, so getting the list of attributes from a product is not the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the answer lies in this model

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_set_api')->items($setId);
```

The class is `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Api` it seems to have two methods. The items() methods seems to do what you ask i.e. ***"Retrieve attributes from specified attribute set"***

I hope that helps :)

Comment: I think you mean `Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_api')->items($setId);`, `...attribute_set_api` would give a `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Set_Api`, correct?

Answer (score 16):

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_set_api')->items();
```

Gets the attribute sets themselves.

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_api')->items($setId);
```

Gets the attributes *inside* the attribute sets.

Answer (score 7):

The right way:

```
$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
->setAttributeSetFilter($attributeSetId)
->getItems();
var_dump($attributes);
```

You can change resources 'catalog/product_attribute_collection' (customer, ...)
And Set ID $attributeSetId

Answer (score 3):

Regarding Attribute Set, there is a good collection of code snippets in the following blog article:
http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/playing-with-attribute-set-in-magento/

Hope you will find them useful.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need to access the API class. There is a more natural approach available. If you have a product:

```
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product **/
$attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($product);
```

If not:

```
$attributes = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()
  ->loadAllAttributes()
  ->getSortedAttributes($attributeSetId);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for an answer, I could'nt find it and I solve my problem with these lines;

```
        $attributeSetId = /* set id */;
        $attributes = array();

        $groups = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_group')
            ->getResourceCollection()
            ->setAttributeSetFilter($attributeSetId)
            ->setSortOrder()
            ->load();

        foreach ($groups as $node) {

            $nodeChildren = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
                ->setAttributeGroupFilter($node->getId())
                //->addFieldToFilter('is_user_defined', true) # I was trying to get user defined attributes.
                ->addVisibleFilter()
                ->load();

            if ($nodeChildren->getSize() > 0) {
                foreach ($nodeChildren->getItems() as $child) {
                    $attr = array(
                        'id'                => $child->getAttributeId(),
                        'text'              => $child->getAttributeCode()
                    );

                    $attributes[] = $attr;
                }
            }
        }

        var_dump($attributes);
```